# How to make a bash script execute programs one after the other instead of all at once?

Tags: bash

Disclaimer: I have zero programming experience.

I have hundreds of files that need to be modified by a program called fastq-mcf. I was hoping to create a bash script that would do this for me, one file at a time. In other words, the program would modify my file, finish, then move on to the next. I've done this successfully using other programs such as wget and cat so I thought this would be straight forward. But unfortunately when I try my script all the files start being edited at once, which is of course too much for my computer to process.

This is an example of my script with just two files to process:

```
#!/bin/bash

/Applications/fastq-mcf -o MAP346_1.mcf.fasta -o MAP346_2.mcf.fasta -q 20 -D 50 -S -w 4 -x 10 -u /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/fastqmcf_trim/NexteraPE-PE.fasta /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/raw_data/4898_2708_17422_HBGAEADXX_MAP346_TAGGCATG-ACTGCATA_R1.fastq.gz /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/raw_data/4898_2708_17422_HBGAEADXX_MAP346_TAGGCATG-ACTGCATA_R2.fastq.gz &>rMAP346.log &

/Applications/fastq-mcf -o MAP345_1.mcf.fasta -o MAP345_2.mcf.fasta -q 20 -D 50 -S -w 4 -x 10 -u /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/fastqmcf_trim/NexteraPE-PE.fasta /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/raw_data/4898_2708_17421_HBGAEADXX_MAP345_TAGGCATG-GTAAGGAG_R1.fastq.gz /Users/pdm37/Documents/MAP/sequencing_results/raw_data/4898_2708_17421_HBGAEADXX_MAP345_TAGGCATG-GTAAGGAG_R2.fastq.gz &>rMAP345.log &
```

to simplify it

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/fastq-mcf output_file1 output_file2 -options necessary_info_file input_file1 input_file2 &>r12.log &

/path/fastq-mcf output_file3 output_file4 -options necessary_info_file input_file3 input_file4 &>r34.log &
```

I tried adding a semicolon instead of the return between the two lines but that didn't help, it just said that an unexpected character occurred.

I really hope you can help me. Maybe there is a simple fix, or maybe I need to about this very differently? Ideally, I would use your solution to then further process these files with other programs so it would be a huge help to know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Drop the `&` at the end. That says "run in the background".

Comment: That seemed to fix the first problem - it started running just the first line. But then it came up with this error: /fastqmcf_round1_test1.sh: line 3: 17460 Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: actually I think I may have fixed this now by deleting all the spaces between the lines and then hitting return twice. So whatever formatting was there has been removed (I'm using textedit)

Comment: A segmentation fault in `/Applications/fastq-mcf` is virtually guaranteed to be unrelated to script formatting (especially unquoted line whitespace since it never even sees that).

Comment: must have done something else wrong then. Nevertheless, it's working now. Thank you ever so much!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash script order of execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445846/bash-script-order-of-execution)

Comment: As a duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702536/sequentially-run-commands-in-bash-script is closer but it doesn't have any upvoted answers so I can't mark it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ensure that command 1 finishes successfully before going on to command 2, you can use &&

```
command 1 && command 2
```

.  There is also the `wait` command but I don't know much about it.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=92761